# Entity Framework many to many mapping with additional field

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a many to many mapping table setup in my SQL Server database which has a primary key composed by the foreign key to the two tables. When I generate the entities model from the database it works great by creating the association with the two tables.

However when I add an additional column to that table (Sort Order) the association breaks and it complains that every column needs to be mapped.

Is there a way to have a many to many relationship with an additional column using Entity Framework?

Comment: Your *only* option is to pull the junction table into your class model, for instance by removing the two many-to-many entities and re-adding them and the join table.

Comment: That's not good since I would be losing my navigation properties between the two tables.

Comment: But you're probably right and it might be my only choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find when using Database First that Mappings don't work properly when relationships are involved and you "Update Model from Database" or add columns and the like

The only solution i have found to date is making the changes to the database outside EF and then literally deleting the model and remaking it.. which kind of defeats some of the point of using EF in the first place..

If there is a better way, I would certainly like to know as-well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try not updating my model and accessing that column from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I create an explicit model for many to many relationships. Then it's easy to add Metadata to those relationships if you need it later rather than being stuck with the auto generated table from the detected many to many relationship.

This is assuming you're using code first*

Comment: I'ts too late for that, I'm already using database first. I could still make the necessary changes in the designer, but I don't see how can I map that column in the association.